# Adjusting picture box based on combo box

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ComboBox1.SelectedValue IsNot Nothing Then
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\goodisam000\Desktop\Goodin Coding\Stuff\Pokemon Sprites\X and Y\xyani\" & (ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString.ToLower) & ".gif")
    End If
End Sub
```

I am wanting to have the picture box change the image based on the combo box option selected. So say i choose Abra in the combo box, i then want the form to load Abra's image into the picture box upon selecting Abra.

Comment: Tag your question properly.  This is either VB.NET or VBA.  Something you should know the difference between.

Comment: @Dan-o sorry again it's vb.net

Comment: how does what you have fail?

Comment: @Plutonix the picture box doesn't load the desired image. no errors when executing the code it's just the picture box doesn't change the image

Comment: @TheBlueDog that's all the code i have for the project...

Answer (score 0):

What about adding the image to your resources then linking from the resource place?

Then you can have the image as "resources\\imageblabla" instead of "C:\Users\goodisam000\Desktop\Goodin Coding\Stuff\Pokemon Sprites\X and Y\xyani\"

- You could try it?